# DataSpell no "New Project" and other path related things messed up

Tags: python, dataspell

In DataSpell, my New Project and Open Project buttons are replaced by New Workspace Directory and Attach Directory respectively.

I want my buttons back! When I try to open any previous projects they now show an error, "Cannot attach project: Module already exists: stuff.iml" (although they open). All Jupyter servers are listed as "outside of current module" (but still work). All my files are highlighted as light yellow, meaning they are "outside of project" and smart refactor, etc dont work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to open each project in separate window/workspace, right?

I don't find a way by using the DataSpell UI, but I find a work around by using Jetbrains [command line launcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#arguments). Then you can use `dataspell .` to open the project in the current directory.

People are voting the feature in this [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2106/Support-multiple-projects-workspaces), you can also vote there.

Comment: The new Project button should be back in the EAP version which is going to be released in early March 2023